# CSS Overflow Issue iPad

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

I am having a problem in my CSS on iPad ONLY. It's a problem only when I have the `#wrapper` have Native iOS 5 Scrolling (`-webkit-overflow-scrolling`). I know something is clashing but I can't figure out how to fix it. `overlow: hidden;` is enabled on both.

It should look like [image: this]

But It looks like this on iPad only when `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is enabled
[image]

[Here is the demo.](http://dacheezypuffs.webs.com/wordpress/index.html)

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, you should add your own answer and then accept it - to help others that search for the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I figured out the problem. The overflow:hidden; on the images are clashing with the -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; on the wrapper around the whole page

Answer (score 0):

I went to the website on my iPad 2 running ios 5 and it's perfect.  I don't seen any problems.  I click on it and it pops up the title and description, so it may be you or it could be loading something in the wrong order.  I've had stuff like that happen to me before.

Comment: It's because I figured out the problem. The overflow:hidden; on the images are clashing with the -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; on the wrapper around the whole page